# Append data to excel using perl

Tags: excel, perl, append

I am new to Perl.Can anyone tell me how to append data from one excel file to another existing excel file?

I have 2 excel files and 1 excel file is created every time I run the program but I need to copy the data from new excel file to another one as a backup. so I want to append the data to the backup file.

I tried searching in web but all i am getting is creating new files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want [**Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser**](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet%3a%3aParseExcel%3a%3aSaveParser)

```
# Open an existing file with SaveParser
my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser->new();
my $template = $parser->Parse('template.xls');
my $row  = #Enter row value here, keep incrementing it for appending
my $col  = #Enter column value here
# Add a cell
$worksheet->AddCell( $row, $col, 'New string' );
# Write over the existing file or write a new file.
$template->SaveAs('newfile.xls');
```

Comment: Thank you Chankey, but i am getting an error "Can't call method "AddCell" on an undefined value at ./6.pl line 16".

Comment: I think you added my code as it is, that's not how you do it, it's just a sample. Go to the module page and see the documentation.